# Pandas: selecting specific rows and specific columns using .loc() and/or .iloc()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({
    
'id': [1, 17, 19, 17, 22, 3, 0, 3],
'color': ['Green', 'Blue', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'White', 'Silver', 'Purple', 'Black'],
'shape' : ['Circle', 'Square', 'Circle', 'Triangle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Square', 'Triangle'],
'person' : ['Sally', 'Bob', 'Tim', 'Sue', 'Bill', 'Diane', 'Brian', 'Sandy']
    
})

df

    id      color     shape       person
0   1       Green     Circle      Sally
1   17      Blue      Square      Bob
2   19      Orange    Circle      Tim
3   17      Yellow    Triangle    Sue
4   22      White     Rectangle   Bill
5   3       Silver    Circle      Diane
6   0       Purple    Square      Brian
7   3       Black     Triangle    Sandy
```

I set the index to `color`:

`df.set_index ('color', inplace = True )`

```
          id    shape       person
color           
Green     1     Circle      Sally
Blue      17    Square      Bob
Orange    19    Circle      Tim
Yellow    17    Triangle    Sue
White     22    Rectangle   Bill
Silver    3     Circle      Diane
Purple    0     Square      Brian
Black     3     Triangle    Sandy
```

I'd like to select only the columns `id` and `person` and only the indices 2 and 3.  To do so, I'm using the following:

```
new_df = df.loc[:, ['id', 'person']][2:4]

new_df

          id    person
color       
Orange    19    Tim
Yellow    17    Sue
```

It feels like this might not be the most 'elegant' approach.  Instead of tacking on `[2:4]` to slice the rows, is there a way to effectively ***combine*** `.loc` (to get the columns) and `.iloc` (to get the rows)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you know the index names you could just use `loc`. Or am I misunderstanding?

`df.loc[["Orange", "Yellow"], ['id', 'person']]`

Comment: @bkeesey -- I don't know the index names beforehand (only that it should be indices 2 and 3).

Comment: Like @rafaelc said you can first `loc` with the index values and then set the index if you don't know what the `color` value will be.

`df.loc[[2, 3], ['color', 'id', 'person']].set_index("color")`

Comment: After I already set the index to `color`, this is giving me a key error:  `KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([2, 3], dtype='int64', name='color')] are in the [index]"`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can start with `df.iloc` (specifying slices or arbitrary indices) and filter column names at the end:

```
df.iloc[[2,3]][['id', 'person']]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to remove `df.set_index('color', inplace=True)` and use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) this way :

```
new_df = df.loc[2:3, ['color', 'id', 'person']].set_index('color')
```

​
Output :

```
print(new_df)

        id person
color            
Orange  19    Tim
Yellow  17    Sue
```

Comment: **NB**: Contrary to usual python slices, both the *start* and the *stop* are included ([*source*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)).